# Prove $T: \ell_p \to \ell_p \ (x_n)_{n\ge1} \mapsto (x_{n+1}−x_{n})_{n \ge 1}$ is a bounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $1≤p≤\infty$ and  $$ T:\ell_p \mapsto \ell_p $$ defined as  $$
>  T((x_n)_{n\geq1}) = (x_{n+1}−x_{n})_{n \geq 1} $$where  $$ 
>  (x_n)_{n\geq 1} = ((x_n)_1, (x_n)_2, (x_n)_3, \ldots), $$
>
> Prove that it is a bounded linear operator.

I need hint for solution:

I computed norm using Minkowski inequality of  $$||T((x_n)_{n\geq 1})||_{p} = ||(x_{n+1}−x_{n})_{n \geq 1}||_{p} \leq ||x_{n+1}||_{q} + ||x_{n}||_{p} $$ where $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$ 
So $||x_{n+1}||_{q} < 0 $ because $x_{n+1} \in \ell_p$

But I am not sure why arguing that $||\color{red}( x_{n} \color{red})||_{q} < \color{red} \infty  $

It is correct thinking?

Comment: First: only use $p$. The $q$ is not needed here. Second: you cannot write $\|x_n\|_p$ because $x_n$ is a number. Instead, write $\|(x_n)\|_p$. Third: $\|(x_n)\|_p < 0$ does not make sense. I guess you mean something else... But your reasoning using the triangle inequality is fine.

Comment: What do you mean by $(x_n)_{n\geq 1} = ((x_n)_1, (x_n)_2, (x_n)_3, \ldots)$? Isn't it just $(x_n)_{n \ge 1} = (x_1, x_2, \ldots)$?

Comment: For first I used compute for third it's mistake will be $\infty$ In first

Comment: Have you shown the linearity?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik I have issue only $T(X_{n}+Y_{n})$

Comment: $T(x + y) = (x_{n+1} + y_{n+1} - (x_n + y_n))_{n \ge 1} =  (x_{n+1} - x_n )_{n \ge 1} + (y_{n+1}-y_n)_{n \ge1} = T(x) + T(y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, but are confusing notation.
To show that $T$ is bounded, we show that for its operator norm $\| T \| < \infty$ holds.
This is equivalent to the existence of some $M \in [0, \infty)$ such that $\| T x \|_{\ell^p} \le M \| x \|_{\ell^p}$ for all $x \in \ell^p$.

As you pointed out we have for $x = (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^p$
\begin{align}
\| T x \|_{\ell^p}
& = \| (x_{n + 1} - x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|_{\ell^p}
\overset{\triangle \ne}{\le} \| (x_{n + 1})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|_{\ell^p} + \| (x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|_{\ell^p} \\
& = \left( \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} | x_{n + 1}|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} + \left( \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} | x_{n}|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}
= \left( \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} | x_{n}|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} + \left( \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} | x_{n}|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \\
& \le 2 \left( \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} | x_{n}|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}
= 2 \| (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|_{\ell_p},
\end{align} 
yielding $M = 2 < \infty$, where $\triangle \ne$ denotes the triangle inequality for the $p$-norm.

---

Also, the [Minkowski inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality) is $\| f + g \|_{p} \le  \| f \|_{p} + \| g \|_{p}$, no $q$s involved. It is true, however, that $\| x y \|_1 \le \| x \|_p \| y \|_q$, for $x,y \in \ell_1$ where $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}$, which is the Hölder inequality.